# Biblatex abbrevation for no editor second try

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, strings

Referring to my previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213987/45570) I now try to solve the problem with the missing editor for a proceeding or inproceeding entry. So if I write the command `\noeditor` into the field `editor` one should get the result `s.ed.` without the additional `, ed.` for the proceeding enty and without the `Ed. by.` for the inproceeding entry.

I've manage to find the `editor+otherstring` bibmacro in the *.bbx file. However, I'm not sure if I need to edit this bibmacro or if there is an easier way allowing me to switch the bib style without editing the bibmacro of each style?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
% Example for no editor
@Proceedings{10,
    title                       = {Proceedings of the 1st International Conference on sth},
    year                        = {2010},
    publisher               = {A Publisher},
    editor                  =   {\noeditor},
    venue                       = {London, England},
    eventdate               = {2010-01-01/2010-01-03},
    eventtitle          = {1st International Conference on sth}
}
@Inproceedings{XY10,
 crossref                   = {10},
 author                     = {LastName, FirstName and Lastname2, FirstName2},
 title                      = {Some nice title},
 pages                      = {10--20},
 bookpagination     = {page}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\nocite{*} 

\begin{document}
\null
\vfill

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mhhh, in your MWE I obviously get the error that `\noeditor` is undefined. If I take all the code in cfr's answer (that is the redefinitions of `editor` and `editor+others` as well) and add your example entries above to the test database entries there, there is no superfluous comma. Everything seems fine. So maybe I'm missing something? Anyway, I only noticed that after I had conjured up my competing approach you find in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following which will always write "S.ed." if you are missing the editor field (and `useeditor` is turned on: compare and contrast `britannica` and `10` in the MWE below).

Just like cfr we have

```
\NewBibliographyString{noeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  noeditor      =   {s\adddot ed\adddot},
}
```

But then

```
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \ifuseeditor
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\bibstring{noeditor}}
      {\printnames{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
       \clearname{editor}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifuseeditor
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\bibstring{noeditor}}
      {\printnames{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
       \clearname{editor}}}
    {}}
```

print `noeditor` when there is no editor.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
% Example for no editor
@Proceedings{10,
  title      = {Proceedings of the 1st International Conference on sth},
  year       = {2010},
  publisher  = {A Publisher},
  venue      = {London, England},
  eventdate  = {2010-01-01/2010-01-03},
  eventtitle = {1st International Conference on sth},
}
@Inproceedings{XY10,
  crossref  = {10},
  author    = {LastName, FirstName and Lastname2, FirstName2},
  title     = {Some nice title},
  pages     = {10--20},
}
@collection{britannica,
  editor       = {Preece, Warren E.},
  title        = {The {New Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica}},
  date         = 2003,
  edition      = 15,
  volumes      = 32,
  publisher    = {Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica},
  location     = {Chicago, Ill.},
  options      = {useeditor=false},
  label        = {EB},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*} 

\NewBibliographyString{noeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  noeditor      =   {s\adddot ed\adddot},
}


\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \ifuseeditor
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\bibstring{noeditor}}
      {\printnames{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
       \clearname{editor}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifuseeditor
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\bibstring{noeditor}}
      {\printnames{editor}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
       \clearname{editor}}}
    {}}


\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example bibliography]

Comment: Thank you. I get warnings from biblatex that the `Bibliography string 'noeditor' is undefined`. I've entered everything like you did in your example. Have I missed sth.?

Comment: @user2653422 The MWE I posted does not have this problem on my machine, I can assure you. Did you really copy and paste that? Do you maybe have an outdated version of `biblatex`? Do you get any other warnings or errors? Are you perchance writing in another language than English?

Comment: Ok if I only use your MWE it works. I've copied your MWE into my workspace where I have lots of other files. So I think I need to figure out where the clash is.

Comment: @user2653422 Mhhh, without seeing the code you tried it is of course just guesswork, but you might be missing the `\NewBibliographyString{noeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  noeditor      =   {s\adddot ed\adddot},
}` bit. Note that if you don't write in English, but in, say, Spanish you need `\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}`. If the problem persist, try to narrow it down by producing an MWE of the non-working solution.

Comment: @user2653422 Ah, yes, you will have to define the necessary BibliographyStrings for all the languages you use in your document.

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to prevent biblatex from automatic capitalizing the `s` of the `s.ed.`? I've tried putting `{` and `}` around the `s`, but this is ignored.

Comment: @user2653422 Try putting an empty group `{}`  in front of the `s`: `noeditor = {{}s\adddot ed\adddot}`.